# Is there a way to use VirusTotal.com offline?

Tags: antivirus, software

I live at a place where we don't always always have internet. I wonder if there is something like VirusTotal but that could work without internet connection and sync when I have some wifi to update its database.

Comment: VirusTotal is nothing more than a collection of all the AV engines that tests a submitted file. If you want to setup offline scans, you can configure VMs or docker images for the AVs you want to test against. The point and advantage of VT is all due to it being online since updates are pushed in real time. If there was presumably an offline version (there isn't any), it would be off little use anyway.

Comment: You can build your own private version of virus total with something like this [Malice](https://github.com/blacktop/malice) or [CloudAV](https://github.com/bourkey08/cloudavwizard)

Answer (score 1):

You could have a Virtual Machine set up, and buy subscriptions to/download the free versions of all the anti-virus engines you like (for instance, the list VirusTotal has), install them one at a time (making sure to turn off all the automatic features except updating - no on-line scanning, no email integration, no Web Toolbar, no SafeSearch, no URL checking, etc. etc.).

Then you could copy a file to the VM or use shared storage or whatever and scan it with every engine.  The more advanced method, of course, is to automate the scans with each engine - either a batch file, or a program that calls each of them one at a time and reports the results.

You can then bring the VM online and update them all whenever you can/need to; again, automating that will help keep your workload down.  You can also take snapshots of the VM and be able to go back to previous version to see if a particular piece of malware was detected differently some time ago; i.e. to track the change in detection, though that's a bit cumbersome and snapshots will slow down performance and use drive space.

Comment: There are plenty of frameworks that essentially automate this.

Answer (score 1):

[IRMA](http://irma.quarkslab.com/index.html) is a good offline alternative to VirusTotal and is open-source!

Like the others say it's nothing more than a collection of AVs at the difference that they working all together correctly. You give your file once instead of giving it to all your AVs.

This answer is maybe late for you but it can serve others.

Comment: Please try to avoid product recommendations on this forum. Products can easily become outdated and result in your answer not being useful anymore

Answer (score 0):

I used a program that downloaded the AV definitions and did everything offline. You can find it on blackhat forums I guess, I don't remember the name of it, though.

The reason they use it, is so while developing their malware, they can scan it without the antivirus companies receiving any kind of information on the scanned files.

Comment: Whats the name of that software,

Comment: I don't recall. It was released with even the source code on my favourite source code portal for trojans   (trojan-france.com  or something like that. It was 7-10 years ago I think)